# Which is better practice between passing ActiveRecord Objects vs database table ids to a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop

I have a rake task that pulls data from the database (Event Model) for events that
  have status 'Open' and processes these Events by calling methods in two different
  classes. The first one batches up the events based on some condition and the other is a
  crawler that generates a CSV for these event batches and uploads that CSV to an external
  website thereafter updating the status of each event referencing those batches after the
  crawl finishes executing.

There are two ways I pass the Active Record objects to these two classes' methods.

1. Passing the ActiveRecord objects to the two classes (my current implementation)
2. Passing the object's database table ids and just do a fetch from each of
   those classes.

Which of these options has less of a *'smell'* to it. My brain tells me that passing the ids
  would have a performance downside by doing another database query once the ids get to
  the other class. On the other hand passing ActiveRecord objects with all that data seems
  superflous since all that will be updated is the status. So which option is the better one? I've included the rake task just to get a clear picture of what I mean.

```
  desc "Process open Events ..."
  task :process_open_events => :environment do
    open_events = Event.find_all_by_status("Open")
    event_batches = EventUtils::EventProcessor.create_event_batches(open_events)
    crawler = EventsCrawler.create!
    crawler.enqueue_crawler(event_batches)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you'd read (and hold in memory) a list of records, then map their ids to an array (also held in memory), send that array over to another method and not just rerun the query which you know will have identical results, but put a duplicate of that initial list into memory as well.

Working with a list of ids would seem to me to be less efficient in every way, processing time, memory usage, database usage.